# Java KeyListener not working or being added

Tags: java, keylistener

I am programming snake for my school and everything works totally fine, except for the keyListener. I don't really know where the problem is, because I think that I called the right way.

Here is the code of my window class:

```
package GUI;

import Entity.Apple;
import Entity.Schlange;
import Threads.Threads;
import Threads.KeyInput;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    public Window() {
        Spielfeld spielfeld = new Spielfeld();
        Apple apple = new Apple(0, 0, spielfeld);
        KeyInput keyInput = new KeyInput(); // This is the keyListener
        Schlange schlange = new Schlange(spielfeld, apple, keyInput);

        Threads thread = new Threads(spielfeld, apple, schlange);

        this.setTitle("Snake");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);

        this.add(spielfeld);
        this.pack();

        this.addKeyListener(keyInput);
        this.setVisible(true);

        thread.startThread();
    }
}
```

And from the keyListener:

```
package Threads;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class KeyInput implements KeyListener {
    public Queue<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        String moved = new String();
        System.out.println("keyTyped");

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            System.out.println("W gedrückt");
            moved = "up";
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            System.out.println("W gedrückt");
            moved = "left";
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            System.out.println("W gedrückt");
            moved = "down";
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            System.out.println("W gedrückt");
            moved = "right";
        }

        queue.add(moved);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("keyTyped");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("keyTyped");
    }
}
```

The keyListener is supposed to be added to the window, and then be given to "Schlange" (Germ.: Snake), where it will be proced.

I have a lot of lines with System.out.println() to debug, but none of them gave out anything and it doesn't matter what I click.

Should I like add it in the JPanel?

Edit: I tried adding it to the JPanel "Spielfeld", which worked

Comment: I tried to put the .pack() under the .addKeyListener(), but neither worked it than

Comment: For a snake game, I will say you'll likely be more interested in `#keyPressed` than `#keyTyped`: you're not interested in text entry (holding down and typing multiple characters) or the release (you should already be moving that direction if you hold it down then release), but instead changing direction exactly when someone tells you to (pressing the key down).

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. Instead you should be using Key Bindings.

Comment: Use [Key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener` - everything else is irrelevant

Comment: Also, while we're at it, Swing is not thread safe, you should not be updating the UI or modify any state the UI relies on from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three points I can hint at:

### Problem #1:

Do NOT write the same message to sysout for different events, this will confuse you, so instead, for each method write its real name and add the parameter:

- `System.out.println("KeyInput.keyTyped(e=" + e + ")");`
- `System.out.println("KeyInput.keyPressed(e=" + e + ")");`
- `System.out.println("KeyInput.keyReleased(e=" + e + ")");`).

This way you will see WHAT is triggered WHERE.

This is mainly important, because certain keys will not trigger all 3 events (pressed, released, typed).

### Problem #2:

If you do NOT add the panel `spielfeld`, the evets will in fact all get triggered. As I cannot see what your `Spielfeld` class is, I bet it catches ('consumes') those events.

Quick fix:  instead of adding the keylistener to `this` (`this.addKeyListener(keyInput);`), better add them to `spielfeld`: `spielfeld.addKeyListener(keyInput);`, maybe that works then.

(And please, next time, provide ALL relevant code)

### Problem #3:

Actually, a bunch of small problems: You did not describe your actual problem. Do the events not get triggered at all? What output messages do you get? Maybe there's a swallowed Exception somewhere that is relevant to this problem. Include a runnable example with ALL relevant classes. Usually when dumbing down the problem, you see the solution yourself.

So, I hope this already helped. In any way, please update your question, so if future generations come here looking for the same problem, they'll have better info.